# Obj-C: How to Deserailize JSON to a collection of xyz model object array?

Tags: objective-c

I am receiving a collection of object (given below)

```
{
 "couponCollection": [
  {
   "validTill": "2015-11-30 00:00:00",
   "couponType": "1",
   "description": "This coupon will give you free trial of 30 days",
   "couponCode": "free30"
  },
  {
   "validTill": "2015-11-30 00:00:00",
   "couponType": "1",
   "description": "This coupon will give you free trial of 30 days",
   "couponCode": "free30"
  },
  {
   "validTill": "2015-11-30 00:00:00",
   "couponType": "1",
   "description": "This coupon will give you free trial of 30 days",
   "couponCode": "free31"
  }
 ]
}


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "JsonModelLib/JSONModel.h"

@interface CouponDetailsModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *couponType;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *couponCode;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *validTill;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *des;

@end
```

I need to de-serialize the above JSON into a CouponDetailsModel object array. I am using  **[JsonModelLib](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModelLib.h)**.

**What I have tried so far**

```
NSMutableArray* list = [[CouponDetailsModel alloc] initWithString:jsonData error:nil];

for (int i =0; i<[list count]; i++) {
    CouponDetailsModel* obj = (CouponDetailsModel*) [list objectAtIndex:i];
```

> Printing description of obj: {
>       couponCode = free30;
>       couponType = 1;
>       description = "This coupon will give you free trial of 30 days";
>       validTill = "2015-11-30 00:00:00"; }

```
    NSString* code = [obj couponCode]; // here is an error (given below)
}
```

**Above code that is giving given below error**

```
2015-11-16 15:27:33.825 myProj[2283:82450] -[__NSCFDictionary couponCode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800026f2c0
2015-11-16 15:27:33.826 myProj[2283:82450] -[__NSCFDictionary couponCode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800026f2c0
2015-11-16 15:27:33.964 myProj[2283:82450] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8203403c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8cdae76e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff820370ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81f7ce24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81f7c998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Common                              0x00000001000bccba -[APIHelper getAvailableCoupons] + 362
    6   myProj                            0x0000000100005377 -[CouponsView windowDidLoad] + 423
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff88ab6857 -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] + 586
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff88a9eb83 -[NSWindowController window] + 110
    9   myProj                            0x000000010000278d -[ActivationScreenView showCoupons:] + 221
    10  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff88578cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b3eeb1 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 452
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b54946 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b54862 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
    14  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff88578cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b547bf -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
    16  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff88578cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b52cb3 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2821
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff88bab34f -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 770
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b51366 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 714
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff890bb2dc -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 14125
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a4ac86 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 470
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a47212 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2504
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff88970b68 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff888ed244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    25  myProj                            0x0000000100004a02 main + 34
    26  myProj                            0x0000000100001bb4 start + 52
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong or asked a question

Comment: @Cristik @ Wain : Many thanks for your attention. I have updated my question and added what I have tried. Please have a look

Comment: @VikasBansal what problems do you experience with the code? What doesn't work? Please also add this detail to the question.

Comment: @Cristik Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the question again as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSJsonSerilization class that converts json objects into dictionary.... then from that dictionary you can get a particular object by using method 
[dicName objectforkey:Key];
This will return data for that key... in your case this key is couponCollection.

which will return you array in which you can get all details of coupons.

Comment: I am able to do is via NSDictionary however I want to do it using class model object. Is it possible?

Comment: you can read your dictionary values and can set them on your class variables which can be accessed later anywhere.